# Javascript change src works on one page, not on the other

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm a total noob, so go easy on me.....

I have a rails app, where I'm letting users vote on links.  When they are eligible to vote, I have an image with a green thumb as my button.  After they vote, the image changes to white and I increase the number of votes.  Here's the code:

```
var html = "<%= @link.votes_count + 1 %>";
var container = $("#link-<%= @vote.link.id %>");
container.find('.count').text(html)
container.find('.thumb').attr('disabled', true)
container.find('.thumb').attr('src', 'assets/thumb.png')
```

On my index page, this works perfectly.  The counter increases by 1, the button no longer votes and it changes to the white thumb.  On the show page, it's using the exact same lines of code.  The counter still increases by 1, the old image disappears, but the white thumb does not show up.  When I look at the console, the index request that works is using an image/png as the type of request, while the show request that doesn't is using a text/html request.  It's also inserting the word links into my src.  So instead of /assets/thumb.png, it's using /links/assets/thumb.png.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your src is relative, and you should use an absolute path.

Like this (in the last line):

```
container.find('.thumb').attr('src', '/assets/thumb.png')
```

Comment: Ahaha another noob here. Could you please mark the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Might be an issue with your link src, have you tried `'/assets/thumb.png'` instead of `'assets/thumb.png'`?